# How to implement a "ArrayLike" class in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm wondering how to implement an `ArrayLike` class in TypeScript.
Anyone knows how to do this?

edited: This is the answer from @jcalz , works for me.

```
class FooList<T> implements ArrayLike<T> {
  length: number
  [n: number]: T
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to implement array-like class with custom methods with Typescript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37159090/how-to-implement-array-like-class-with-custom-methods-with-typescript)

Comment: Please provide a [mre]; it doesn't look like you care about `Iterable<T>` from the text of your question, and implementing `Iterable<T>` from scratch is fairly annoying so if you really want that you should ask about it explicitly.  Also, `FooList` is not generic so the example doesn't compile... presumably you want `class FooList<T>`?  Or is `T` some specific type?  Anyway if you just want to implement `ArrayLike<T>` you can do it like [this](https://tsplay.dev/WvV3MW); does that meet your needs?  If not what's missing?

Comment: Thanks @jcalz ! This is what I want! I didn't know TypeScript can do `[n: number]: T` in a class definition, good to know! Thanks!

Comment: So, shall I write up an answer?  If so, could you [edit] the example code to remove `Iterable<T>` and to make `FooList` generic?

Comment: @jcalz No it's good enough for me! Thanks man!  I have edited my question!

Answer (score 2):

[Classes are allowed to have index signatures](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#index-signatures) just like any other object type.  If you declare that a class has a `number` index signature (as required by [the definition of `ArrayLike<T>`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/b8b1201e4417cd114fe12adb0a1e728acb2ae8af/lib/lib.es5.d.ts#L1463-L1466)), then the compiler will allow you to get and set properties of the class values at numeric indices:

```
class FooList<T> implements ArrayLike<T> {
    length: number
    [n: number]: T
    constructor(init: T[]) {
        this.length = init.length;
        for (let i = 0; i < init.length; i++) {
            this[i] = init[i];
        }
    }
}

const fooList = new FooList(["a", "b", "c"]);
console.log(fooList.length) // 3
console.log(fooList[0]) // "a"
```

Note that unless you enable [the `--noUncheckedIndexedAccess` compiler flag](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-1.html#checked-indexed-accesses---nouncheckedindexedaccess), the compiler will optimistically assume that there is an actual defined  value at every possible numeric index, whereas in fact most such properties will be `undefined`:

```
fooList[12345].toUpperCase() // no compiler error, but
//  RUNTIME ERROR! fooList[12345] is undefined
```

But since regular arrays also have this behavior:

```
const arr: string[] = ["a", "b", "c"];
arr[12345].toUpperCase() // no compiler error, but
//  RUNTIME ERROR! arr[12345] is undefined
```

it's not really a big deal.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FDDGBsEMGdoAgGIHskBkCW0AuAeAKgHxzoC2ADuAKYmUB2W8AggE7OQCeGA1pfkQN7A4wuFVoBzLAAsAXHFoBXEgCNKzISIDatOYpVqAunLwbhoJLWzMFoLEmYAKdLXRZjmgwEo4gkX7jSmAB0YpJScAC8xC5YIXRhANym-gBm9nAOVFjEkXAADAk5ONGucRLShegA1FXevv4NgdCa6Aa5zq4tBkkNwgC+yQMDYBbYcGlomNlRtJQA7ogoGNgOmgBEkGsANHBrytu7oGteSeaWSFQhSOIOE8uxodLeAPTPcADMI+eX4Ne3S1NNHkvHBXrtNiAsMx2D5kndAQBGABM7wALABWAxBOwAVTIZDUAGEYJQHJ5gH04KBIFhQOEHJQ6skztALpQrjdGYUwfDsJpkWjMcR4ApaAATSgpZyUMVwCkgFnZSCsORWZziDy5dabHZ7A5rI7dYBQmH1YTK5j8lEYrG4-FEklkilUml0jKM2F+FlsjkMzzct4Wq2CtqYOCiiVS2ay+VAA)